# Implement onClick inside an OnShowListener AlertDialog kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to replicate a click event inside an OnShowListener of an AlertDialog that works well in Java to prevent the AlertDialog from closing when the BUTTON_POSITIVE is pressed this is my code in Java:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_password_confirm, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_ok)+"", null)
            .create();
    dialog.setTitle("Acceso Supervisor");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    final EditText editPass = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_password_passwordconfirm);
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button btnAceptar = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String pass = editPass.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (pass == null || pass.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ingresa una contraseña valida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        if (UsuarioModel.verifySupervisorPassword(getContext(), pass)){
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editPass.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ResumenDocActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Oops! contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,getString(R.string.text_cancel) + "", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editPass.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
    editPass.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editPass.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager= (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(editPass, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    editPass.requestFocus();
```

This code in Java works fine it doesn't close the AlertDialog even if they enter wrong password, but failed to replicate it in Kotlin, this is my code:

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_password_confirm, null)
    var editPass = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_password_passwordconfirm);
    val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_ok),null)
            .create()
    dialog.setTitle("Acceso Supervisor")
    var btnOk = dialog?.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
    dialog.setOnShowListener(object: DialogInterface.OnShowListener{
        override fun onShow(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
            var btnOk1 = dialog.let{ btnOk }
            btnOk1?.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    var pass = editPass.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (pass.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ingresa una contraseña valida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        if (UsuarioModel.verifySupervisorPassword(getContext(), pass)){
                            dialog?.dismiss()
                            val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editPass.windowToken, 0)
                            var rrf = ReporteRetirosFragment.newInstance()
                            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.contenedor_reportes_tpv, rrf)
                                    ?.addToBackStack("reporteRetirosTpvFragment")?.commit()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Oops! contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    dialog.show()
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with me in Kotlin, please?

Answer (score 0):

ok I just went ahead and tried to remake your xml file. I hope it's accurate enough.
Imagine this is your xml file to be inflated into the alert dialog:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="OK"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPass" />
```

Then this code should work and it is much cleaner than what you had written (no offence):

```
    val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_password_confirm, null)
    view.txtTitle.text = "Acceso Supervisor"
    view.btnOK.text = getString(R.string.text_ok)
    val myAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(view)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .show()
    myAlertDialog.btnOK.setOnClickListener {
        val pass = myAlertDialog.editPass.text.toString().trim()
        if (pass.isBlank()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ingresa una contraseña valida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            if (UsuarioModel.verifySupervisorPassword(getContext(), pass)) {
                myAlertDialog.dismiss()
                val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myAlertDialog.editPass.windowToken, 0)
                var rrf = ReporteRetirosFragment.newInstance()
                fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.contenedor_reportes_tpv, rrf)?.addToBackStack("reporteRetirosTpvFragment")?.commit()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be failing because you're calling `getButton` immediately after creating the `Dialog`, before you've called `show` and before it's done a layout pass, so the button might not have been created yet. Your Java code grabs the button during the `onShow` callback, which happens after it's displayed.

Personally I'd put your validation code in another function, and do something like this:

```
val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.setView(view)
        .setTitle("Acceso Supervisor")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_ok)) { handleClick() }
        .create()
```

and then

```
fun handleClick() {
    val pass = myAlertDialog.editPass.text.toString().trim()
        if (pass.isBlank()) {
    ....
}
```

you'll need to store a reference to your created `Dialog` so you can `dismiss` it in that function, since you're not using a `DialogFragment` here.

(also your Java code is different - you're doing `setCancelable(false)` but not in your Kotlin code, and you're also checking for an empty or null password, but in Kotlin you're only checking for an empty one - you can do `if (pass.isNullOrBlank())` and that should handle all whitespace characters, and you don't need to `trim()` the string)